# How to find out lowest API level required for ViewPager

Tags: android, api

I would like to use the `ViewPager` functionality and download **Support Package: revision 4** (October 2011).

This requires API 10 but I want to develop my app for the lowest possible API - ideally 7 or so.

How can I find out which is the lowest API I need to use ViewPager and which library I need to download and include in my app?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for 
[this ?](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/view/ViewPager.java?r=3488)

Comment: Yes, that looks promising!!! Do you know if there is a sample code showing how to use this somewhere?

Comment: Could you please help and tell me how I can use this? I tried to download the complete set of files but I don't really know what I have to do. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Read about the Android Support Package (r4) here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

"Minimum API level supported: 4"

"... the library that supports API level 4 and up is located at `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`"

`<sdk>` is where you unpacked the Android SDK.